# Why can't I pass arguments with units to F# types?

Tags: f#, constructor, units-of-measurement

Suppose I have defined a unit of measure:

`[<Measure>] type Blob`

And I want a type that takes a value in Blobs per second as a constructor argument:

`type Something(flowRate:double<Blob/s>) = ...`

F# throws a wobbly on this - "double does not expect any type arguments, but here is given 1 type argument"

I understand the message. I'd have thought it was obvious what I was trying to do, though I acknowledge that the syntax probably is verifiably wrong. Question is, how do I express this relationship in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the message (sort of) indicates, doubles aren't measure-generic.  Try `float<Blob/s>` instead.  It's a bit strange, since `float` is a type synonym for type `double`.  However, type `float<[<Measure>]'t>` is in some ways its own separate type.  A similar problem occurs with `single` vs. `float32`, `int32` vs. `int`, and `int8` vs. `byte`.  [Section 9.7 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597590) partly covers this information.

It's especially confusing since you can't define your own types which differ only in their measure arity:

```
type T = class end
type T<[<Measure>]'t> = class end //' Duplicate definition of type T
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had assumed that the compiler was trying to tell me 'argument type declarations don't take units' i.e. units go on the end of literals, rather than being types. This makes it simpler.